# How to use OpsWorks App Data Bag (aws_opsworks_app) environment variables in Chef templates?

Tags: chef-infra, gunicorn, aws-opsworks, databags

Given Chef 12 support from OpsWorks was released very recently - all documents I can find are for the Chef 11. So, here is my current setup: flask + gunicorn + nginx on OpsWorks with Chef 12. I use Upstart to start Gunicorn using a template:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid <%= node['conf-cookbook']['gunicorn_user'] %>
setgid <%= node['conf-cookbook']['gunicorn_group'] %>

env MAIL_SERVER="email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
env MAIL_USERNAME="[redcacted]"
env MAIL_PASSWORD="[redacted]"

chdir <%= node['conf-cookbook']['app_dir'] %>

exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:<%= node['conf-cookbook']['gunicorn_socket'] %> -m 007 --log-file <%= node['conf-cookbook']['gunicorn_logfile']%> manage:app
```

I have to include the sensitive environment variable information in the template. In OpsWorks Chef 12, environment variables can be specified using App Data Bag (aws_opsworks_app) and retrieved using something like in deploy recipe (never tried - is it correct):

```
app = search(:aws_opsworks_app).first
app['environment']['MAIL_SERVER']
```

I would like to use the app data bag environment variables to replace the ones I defined in the template file and don't know how. Any one can help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just to confirm, those aren't your real SES credentials, right?

Comment: thanks, I have changed the username and password :)

Comment: Always be careful when copying sensitive data around. Also you don't need to edit my answer into your question.

Comment: You can submit edit suggestions to answers using the link below them.

Comment: Yes. I have deleted my UPDATE and move the edit suggestion to the comment of your answer. Thanks! I have another question: how to make Nginx work with application_python - I see Gunicorn helpers but no Nginx helper. I am really a beginner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary variables data to Chef template resources:

```
template '/etc/init/myapp.conf' do
  source 'myapp.conf.erb'
  variables node['conf-cookbook'].merge(app)
end
```

and then make your template look more like this:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid <%= @gunicorn_user %>
setgid <%= @gunicorn_group %>

<%- @environment.each do |key, value| -%>
env <%= key %>="<%= value %>"
<%- end -%>

chdir <%= @app_dir %>

exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:<%= @gunicorn_socket %> -m 007 --log-file <%= @gunicorn_logfile %> manage:app
```

Also check out the [poise-service](https://github.com/poise/poise-service) and [application_python](https://github.com/poise/application_python) cookbooks, which have helpers for both writing Upstart config files and Gunicorn services respectively.

Comment: you are the man!!! thanks a lot. Amazon should pay you to help them with their documentations :) I will definitely use application framework when I gain more knowledge about Chef. Thanks again.

Comment: I run into another issue - those environment variables are not available for other part of the recipe, for example, after `template '/etc/init/myapp.conf' do... end` I have `execute "setup database" do.. command "python manage.py deploy"..end` that wants to use environment variables - I don't know how. Thanks!!!!

Comment: The `execute` resource has an `environment` property to set environment variables in the command being executed.

Comment: got it, e.g., `environment ({'HOME' => '/home/myhome'})` thx!!